# Squaring inequalities

Tags: inequality

How do I square $-3<x<3$? Logically, $0\le x^2<9$ so what is the rule for squaring inequalities that allows someone to go from $-3<x<3$ to $0\le x^2<9$? It doesn't seem like there is a rule but I wanted to check.

Comment: You could square $$|x|<3$$

Comment: How do you do that?

Comment: Since we now have non-negative values, we can square and get $$|x^2|<9$$ and we can omit now the absolute value to get $$x^2<9$$

Comment: Maybe like this $0\le  |x| <3$; Then $0\le |x||x| \le 3|x| <9$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if $a < x <b$,

if $0 \in (a,b)$, then $0 \le x^2 < \max(a^2, b^2)$

if $0 \notin (a,b)$, then $\min(a^2,b^2) < x^2 < \max(a^2, b^2)$.

Comment: What does $\max(a^2, b^2)$ mean? For my problem I get $\max(9, 9)$, but doesn't this mean the interval where I am trying to see what is the max value has no values because it's ( ) and not [ ]?

Comment: Also shouldn't it be $0 \le x^2 < \max(a^2, b^2)$?

Comment: @user532874 $\max(a^2,b^2)$ simply means the larger of the two values $a^2$ and $b^2$. (Most of the $\leq$ signs in this answer should be replaced with $<$ - the only place you actually need $\leq$ is for the lower bound in the first case.)

Comment: thanks, yes, I was being lazy and included $\le$ for everything just now.

Comment: It's worth note that the condition you get are not equivalent to original ones. For example for $a=-1$, $b=3$ $x=-2$ $$ a<x<b$$ is false but $$ 0 \le x^2 \le \max(a^2,b^2) $$ is true. Similarly, for $a=1$, $b=3$, $x=-2$ $$ a<x<b$$ is false but $$ \min(a^2,b^2) \le x^2 \le \max(a^2,b^2) $$ is true.

Answer (score 0):

Because $$-3<x<3\Leftrightarrow |x|<3\Leftrightarrow x^2<9\Leftrightarrow x^2-9<0\Leftrightarrow(x-3)(x+3)<0.$$

The rule is the following.

If $a\geq0$ and $b\geq0$ then:
$$a\ge b\Leftrightarrow a^2\geq b^2.$$

Answer (score 0):

You can split as

$$-3<x\le0\lor 0\le x<3$$

also written

$$3>-x\ge0\lor 0\le x<3.$$

Now as the inequations only involve positive numbers, you can square and obtain

$$9>x^2\ge0\lor0\le x<9.$$

Answer (score 0):

Let us consider more general case $a<x<b$ where $a<0$ and $b>0$. Function $f(x)=x^2$ is increasing for $x>0$ and decreasing for $x<0$. That means that squaring the ineqality it preserves the sign if both sides are positive, and reverses the sign when both sides are negative. When they are of different signs it can't be said generally.That's why we shall separately consider the cases $x<0$ and $x>0$:
\begin{align} & a<x<b \\
\Leftrightarrow\quad & \big((a<x<b) \land (x<0)\big) \quad \lor \quad \big((a<x<b) \land (0\le x)\big) \\
\Leftrightarrow\quad & \big((a<x) \land (x<0)\big)\quad\lor\quad \big((x<b) \land (0\le x)\big) \\
\Leftrightarrow\quad & \big((x^2<a^2) \land (x<0)\big)\quad\lor\quad \big((x^2<b^2) \land (0\le x)\big) \\
\end{align}
This is generally as far as you can go if you want only equivalent conditions, although for $a^2=b^2$ you can make one more step and simplify it to $x^2=a^2$.

There are however other conditions that can be derived that are not euivalent to the original one, but are necessary or sufficient for it to hold. For example $$ x^2 < \max(a^2,b^2)$$
is a necessary condition, that is $$ (a<x<b )\Rightarrow \big(x^2 < \max(a^2,b^2)\big)$$
It is so because both $x^2<a^2$ and $x^2<b^2$ imply $x^2 < \max(a^2,b^2)$. On the other hand, $$ x^2 < \min(a^2,b^2)$$ is a sufficient condition; because it implies that both $x^2<a^2$ and $x^2<b^2$, so
$$ \big(x^2 < \min(a^2,b^2)\big) \Rightarrow (a<x<b)$$

Comment: I think that `\text{ or }` and `\text{ and }` would be more readable than their logical symbol counterparts. Mixed with $<$ and $>$ it is particularly hard to read.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can square directly only if the inequality is non-negative:
$$-3<x<3 \iff \\
0<x+3<6 \iff \\
0<x^2+6x+9<36 \iff \\
-6x-9<x^2<27-6x \iff \\
-27<0\le x^2<27-6x<9 \iff \\
0\le x^2<9.$$